# How to constrain a sibling view to same height as that of TextInputEditText of an TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to show the label "Km" with a white background with the same height as that of the edit text field.

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutInputDist"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/inputDist"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_left_corner_shape"
                    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:maxEms="4"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_km"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_right_corner_shape"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/km"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayoutInputDist"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayoutInputDist" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the TextInputLayout is taking some more height that the edit text field, I cant align the edit text and the "Km" label vertically the same levels.

Comment: I have added my answer, let me know it's match to your requirement or not. If not I will edit my answer

Comment: Can you please put screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand your question check below answer
>
> Give **kmLable** top and bottom constraint to edit text. Here I give fix width for a temporary purpose (change according to your requirement).

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutInputDist"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inputDist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/dividerColor"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxEms="4"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_km"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/dividerColor"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="km"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayoutInputDist"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayoutInputDist"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayoutInputDist" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The issue with constraining top and bottom is that it will take up the same height as that of the TILayout. But the TIEditText height is less than TILayout. That is the issue I'm facing. I want the label and TIEditText as same height.

Comment: Close but no cigar!  This constrains the TextView to the top and bottom of the TextInputLayout, but it does not align the text correctly like `app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@ textInputLayoutInputDist` would.  Unfortunately TextInputLayout does not make the baseline of its children visible to any siblings--a major omission in Google's implementation of TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
setHintEnabled(false)
```

in your xml like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutInputDist"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:hintEnabled="false">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inputDist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/dividerColor"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:maxEms="4"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```